# How can I tell what encoding settings an MP3 file uses?

Tags: java, audio, encoding, mp3

As per the [`javax.sound.sampled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html#formatted) package, audio format includes:

> - Encoding technique, usually pulse code modulation (PCM)
> - Number of channels (1 for mono, 2 for stereo, etc.)
> - Sample rate (number of samples per second, per channel)
> - Number of bits per sample (per channel)
> - Frame rate
> - Frame size in bytes
> - Byte order (big-endian or little-endian)

*(taken from the Java Tutorials)*

This information is used when making an AudioFormat object to render the audio. I want to play back an MP3 format audio file, but I don't know how I can get all of that information to pass to the AudioFormat.

My question is how do I know what encoding settings a MP3 file uses? For example, what encoding technique does it use (PCM-float, PCM-signed, PCM-unsigned, a-law, u-law)?

Comment: MP3 uses neither of these encodings - simply put: its MP3. And you don't need to know the encoding for just reading a file. Thats what abstractions like AudioInputStream are for: They handle the dirty details under the hood and provide you with a standardized API regardless of actual encoding.

Comment: So why is there an `AudioFormat`? Also, can't MP3s have different sample rates, bit depths, etc.?

Comment: AudioFormat describes a *transport format* within the JRE - *not* a specific file format. AudioFormat is simply part of the abstraction layer used to decouple application logic from physical representation. As for the details of MP3, why don't you simply look it up?

Comment: I did (Wikipedia, the actual specification, and an extremely detailed blog post), but it seems that I have some misconceptions about what is going on. Time for more reading.